# How to make add tick to node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to draw a simple timeline in tikz. Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
Ablauf der Schadenregulierung bei einem typischen Schadenfall
\\ \\

% Zeitstrahl zur Schadenregulierung
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, ultra thick, ->]
(0,0) 
-- (2,0) node [below]{Schadeneintritt}
--(14,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I would like is for there to be a tick on the line at node "Schadeneintritt". I've tried adding `tick` to the options of the node but that produces an error (apparently tickz doesn't know the `tick` option). I'm still new to tikz and so far I've only found solutions for full blown axes / coordinate systems.

I know that I could do:

```
\draw (2,0.2) -- (2,-0.2);
```

but I wonder whether there's an easier solution (i.e. specifying this directly at the node).
Cheers!

Comment: If you name the node `(s)` you can do `\draw ([yshift=.2cm] s.north) -- ++ (down:.4cm);`. Or you use an `append after command` that refers to `(\tikzlastnode.north)` in the same way. Can you generalize the problem? There are many ways to add “ticks” to a line. There’s also the `decorations.markings` library.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is what you're looking to do.  It's not as easy as you seem to want, but it is fairly straight-forward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,10}
    {        
      \coordinate (A\x) at ($(0,0)+(\x*0.5cm,0)$) {};
      \draw ($(A\x)+(0,5pt)$) -- ($(A\x)-(0,5pt)$);
      \node at ($(A\x)+(0,3ex)$) {\x};
    }
  \draw[ultra thick,arrows=->] (A0) -- (A10) -- ($(A10)+1.5*(1,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]