# How to add ticks in a circle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, ticks, tikz-calc

Referring to the question [How to make add tick to node in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132958/how-to-make-add-tick-to-node-in-tikz), how do I extend this to a `circle` shape in TikZ.

A simple approach is to draw lines as ticks by calculating the coordinates. Sample approach below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\draw ($(a.center)-(4.5,0)$) -- (a.west);
\draw ($(a.east)-(0.5,0)$) -- (a.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, this approach is not effective, as the ticks length has to calculated manually.

Is there a better approach to do this (ticks in the circle would be like the lines on an alarm clock, which are inclined execept at 12, 3, 6 and 9 numbers).

Comment: If you don't want to calculate tick lengths, use polar coordinates.

Comment: @JolueV that is a manual calculation as well where there is a chance for error or miscalculation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\foreach` and polar coordinates (with care of course) you can have this

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {60,30,...,-270} {
    \draw (\i:5) -- (\i:4.5);
    \draw (\i:4.2) node[font=\large] {\j};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this code, the for loops iterates through the set {60, 30, 0, −30, −60, −90, −120, −150, −180, −210, −240, −270}. Each of these numbers is the angle of the "ticks". I use polar coordinate based on these iterators, so the angles of the "ticks" are accurate.

I set a counter for the for loop (`\j`) to add numbers to the picture.

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {60,30,...,-270} {
    \draw (\i:5) -- (\i:4.5);
    \draw (\i:4.2) node[font=\large] {\j};
}
\foreach \i in {84,78,...,-270} \draw (\i:5) -- (\i:4.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second for loop is to draw smaller ticks. 84, 78, etc. are the angles of these ticks.

Comment: can you explain the code in the for loop as well please

Comment: @subhamsoni I added some explanations.

Comment: what is \draw (\i:5) -- (\i:4.5)

Comment: @subhamsoni It draws a line joining point (`\i`:5) and point (`\i`:4.5); all of them are polar coordinates. Point (x:y) is defined [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD5zZ.png).

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\draw ($(a.center)-(4.5,0)$) -- (a.west);
\draw ($(a.east)-(0.5,0)$) -- (a.east);
\foreach \X in {0,10,...,350}
{\draw (a.\X) -- ++ (\X:0.2);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

OK, inside.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\foreach \X in {0,10,...,350}
{\draw (a.\X) -- ++ (180+\X:0.2);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\foreach \X in {0,10,...,350}` loops over `\X` in `{0,10,...,350}`, and then the nodes have anchors given in degrees, so `(a.\X)` is a point at the boundary of `a` at the angle `\X`. This syntax is mentioned in [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482058/121799) to one of your questions. `++ (\X:0.2)` adds some shift in polar coordinates, `\X` is the angle and `0.2` the radius. To have the ticks inwards, we need to add 180 degrees to `\X` (one could also use `(\X:-0.2)`.)

And just for fun: a watch.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=10cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\filldraw (a.center) circle [radius=0.1cm];
\foreach \X in {1,...,12}
{\draw (a.-\X*30+90) -- ++ (270-\X*30:0.3) node[pos=1.5]{\X};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the ticks need to be inside like in an alarm clock or watch

Comment: Also can you explain technically the code in the for loop

Comment: @subhamsoni  I added inwards ticks and an explanation.